# Can I add react app to app.html and not to index.html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Assume I already have a static web page `index.html` with its content.

Now after building a [React](https://reactjs.org/) app, I want to create an `href` link to `/app.html` where I would put `<div id="root"></div>` tag, so only when the user navigates to the app page, the React app will be rendered.
How can I set that?

What I did try is basically as presented above: the react app Pablic directory contains an `index.html` with static content, and inside an `href` to `app.html` with a div tag with id="root".
But I get this error:

> Target container is not a DOM element.

Comment: How are you mounting your React app?

Comment: in an index.html's body there is: `<div id="root"></div>`. but I want to put it in other html page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use CDN rather than create-react-app. Then you can add at any HTML file you want. Of course, this will lose some benefits from CRA.

https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html